# Batch Script to delete files past 5 days old

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have a batch script that I have run through Task Scheduler every night at midnight.  Here is the script:

```
forfiles /M *.bak /p "Z:\Logs" /S /D -5 /C "cmd /c del @file : date >= 5 days >NUL"
```

But when the task runs at midnight, it does not delete the files older than 5 days.  If I double click on the batch file and run it manually, it does delete the files older than 5 days.  What is wrong or do I need to do something different to make this work?

EDIT:

Here is my full batch file and more information about the task schedule:

```
sqlcmd -S server\SQLEXPRESS -U user -P password -i "D:\BackupPrograms\translogsbackup.sql"
forfiles /M *.trn /p "Z:\Logs" /S /D -5 /C "cmd /c del @file >NUL"
```

I am using an administrator account for the task schedule to run every night.  I am trying to get it to delete the older backups that the sqlcmd is creating, that way I make sure I am not wasting a bunch of space on Full SQL backups that are not needed.  I hope this helps more.  I am just confused why the batch file would act differently running through the Task Scheduler and when I double click on it to run.

Comment: [When you say that something didn't work, you have to say how it didn't work](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/04/21/9999675.aspx). (There is not enough detail about your problem.)

Comment: I said that the script does not delete the files older than 5 days, when it runs through the task scheduler.  But when I ran it manually it does delete the files older than 5 days.  How is that not enough information?  I am not sure what other information I can provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work from the command prompt any more than it does from the scheduler, and here's why.

```
/C "cmd /c del @file : date >= 5 days>NUL"
```

The `:` is illegal at that position in a command line, and it's ignored.

The `>=` is interpreted as the output redirection symbol, and therefore all of the output is redirected to a file named `5` in the current directory.

You can test this at a command prompt yourself:

1. Create a new, empty folder on your system, such as `C:\Test`, from a command prompt, and make it the active directory.

   ```
   C:\>md Test
   C:\>cd Test
   ```
2. Create a couple of dummy files in the folder:

   ```
   C:\Test>echo file1 > file1.txt
   C:\Test>
   C:\Test>echo file2 > file2.txt
   ```
3. Do a directory to see what's there:

   ```
   C:\Test>dir /b

   file1.txt
   file2.txt

   C:\Test>
   ```
4. Try this `forfiles` command to see the output:

   ```
   C:\Test>forfiles /M *.txt /C "cmd /c echo @file"

   "file1.txt"
   "file2.txt"

   C:\Test>
   ```
5. Change the `forfiles` to add the `: date >= 5 days` and run again:

   ```
   C:\Test>forfiles /M *.txt /C "cmd /c echo @file : date >= 5 days"

   C:\Test>
   ```
6. Do a directory to see what's there:

   ```
   C:\Test>dir /b

   5
   file1.txt
   file2.txt

   C:\Test>
   ```

Note the new file with the name *5*.

So the solution: Delete the `: date >= 5 days`. You can leave the `NUL` portion, as that legitimately redirects any output to NUL (nothing) so that it's not displayed. So your command would look like this:

```
forfiles /M *.bak /p "Z:\Logs" /S /D -5 /C "cmd /c del @file >NUL"
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense now.  Thanks for the example.  So this is what I have now:  forfiles /M *.bak /p "Z:\Logs" /S /D -5 /C "cmd /c del @file NUL"

Comment: See my edited answer (the last paragraph and code sample) for the actual command you should use.

Comment: Ok thank you.  I will let this run over the weekend and I will see if it works.  One last little question, did I really not provide enough information on my first post?

Comment: I thought it was fine, but I'm familiar with batch programming and could spot the problem. I can't speak for others, though. :-)

Comment: Ok thank you very much.  Will let you know if something doesn't work.

Comment: It did not delete the files older than 5 days when the task scheduler ran the batch script.  It is running on a windows server 2012 R2 server.  I have checked to run whether user is logged on or not.  I do have in the batch file to run a sql script to do a backup right before the deletion of the files script that we worked out above.  Is there something that is supposed to go between the two commands?  It is just weird, because if I run the batch script manually it works perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm not sure what "two commands" you're asking about here. The single `forfiles` statement should work fine. I can't speak for the batch file, because I a) can't see the batch file; b) can't see your server to check the account it's running under; and c) I can't see the files you're expecting it to delete that it isn't to see if in fact they're old enough to delete. :-) I can just tell you what the problem was in the `forfiles` command line you were using, because *that* information I have access to here.

Comment: I edited my post up top.  I am just confused why it would run differently from me double clicking on the batch file, to it running itself through the task scheduler?  Thanks for helping me on this!